# right way to alias count * in a subquery

Tags: sql

I have query below as

```
select t.comment_count, count(*) as frequency 
from
(select u.id, count(c.user_id) as comment_count
from users u
left join comments c
on u.id = c.user_id 
and c.created_at between '2020-01-01' and '2020-01-31'
group by 1) t
group by 1
order by 1
```

when I also try to alias the `count(*)` as `count(t.*)` it gives error, can I not alias that with the t from the table? Not sure what I am missing

Thank you

Comment: Your outer query `count(*)` only involves a single derived table, t, so how do you expect the value to differ if you changed to `count(t.*)`? `Count` operates on every logical group of rows. If you need help with the query please edit your answer and include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Count(*)` stands for the count of all rows returned by a query (with respect to `GROUP BY` columns). So it makes no sence to specify one of the involved tables. Consider counting rows produced by a join for example. If you need a count of rows of the specific table `t` you can use `count(distinct t.<unique column>)`